# How to write a program that reads a text file and substitutes certain words and then outputs the text file under a different name

Tags: perl

I've been struggling for the past 3 hours on this homework question and cannot seem to get anywhere.  I've searched online and watched youtube videos.

The question is:
Write a Perl program that reads the input.txt file attached below and write a new file called output.txt. The new file should replace all occurrences (regardless of case) of the character string 'new' with 'old'.

This is what I have so far but can't seem to get anywhere.

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

my $filename = 'WK5input.txt';
open(my $fh,  $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

while (my $row = <$fh>) {
  chomp $row;
  print "$row\n";
}

$_ =~ s/new/old/g;
open( $fh, '>', 'output.txt');

print $filename ;
close $filename;
```

Comment: @AruneshSingh Using `-i` seems to directly contradict what OP explicitly stated to need.

Comment: OP, do you need a separate perl script (as your example implies) or is a commandline one-liner also helpful?

Comment: Is reading a file and writing to a new file to be done from the script, or can shell redirection be used?

Comment: @Yunnosch, Yes, Then I should remove `-i` as `perl -pe 's/new/old/g' WK5input.txt > newfile.txt`

Comment: Cannot resist to provide the reference for homework defying get-it-done-somehow: `sed "s/new/old/gi" WK5input.txt > output.txt`. I hope this is not considered too off-topic, because it illustrates by contrast the special circumstances of homework questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using various shortcuts (which probably are forbidden for your assignment) you could do:
`perl -pe "s/new/old/gi" WK5input.txt > output.txt`

For the special situation of your homework assignment however, you got reasonably close to the goal, but many little details had to be fixed.
(Note that I missed one of those details, the case insensitivity. That would not have happened if you had provided appropriate sample input and desired output. You might want to read up on [mcve].)
I have listed some assumptions on which special side-requirements distinguish your assignment from the usual goal to make an efficient solution.

I intentionally provide a solution here which is as close as possible to your own version, because I believe seeing small changes which make your version work is more helpful to you than the optimised version above. That one is so compact that it completley hides how close you got.
Check the other answers for intermediate versions, neither fully optimised nor homework-oriented.
For an optimised solution, some people would even skip perl and use awk or, for the purpose of historical brain exercise, sed.

These are a few assumptions on implicit rules,
which I guess you are expected to obey:

- write a perl program which covers all the requirements,
  i.e. no use of shell features, no other tools
- do not use commandline parameters
  (just because you did not in your attempt; maybe you have not covered them in your course yet)
- use line by line processing
  (just because you did so in your attempt; maybe you have not covered other methods in your course yet)
- do not use "obscure perl magics", e.g. the commandline options -pe`,
  though they otherwise are highly convenient
  (a special case/interpretation of the "no shell" rule)

If any of these guessed rules are not applicable to your assignment have a look at the other answers. They provide interesting alternatives.

```
# nice touch, using these is very good practice
use strict;
use warnings; 

# Not necessary, but good practice: collect the "my"s in one place soon.
# This supports self-documenting inside the code.
# Doing it with the "my" at the first use is an aleternative option and preferred by some.
my $filename = 'WK5input.txt';  # file name   for the input file
my $fhin;                        # file handle for the input file
my $fhout;                       # file handle for the output file
my $row;                         # variable with currently processed line

# Prefer to use the three parameter version of "open", explicitly stating the mode.
open($fhin, '<', $filename) # two file handles are needed, use different names
  or die 'Could not open input  file "'.$filename.'" '.$!;
# I chose to concatenate both variables (file name and failure reason) explicitly,
# to some text inside '...', which can be more efficiently handled by perl interpreter.
# This saves work on text inside "..." and is more self explaining, i.e. it is easier
# to understand at the first reading what the code does.

# The second file handle is setup here, to read from input and write to output at the same time.
open($fhout, '>', 'output.txt')
  or die 'Could not open output file output.txt '.$!;

while ($row = <$fhin>) { # you are reading into a dedicated variable here ...

  # There was the code "chomp $row;" here. 
  # This removes the newline from ther end of the line, if there is one.
  # It is not needed if you are going to append the newline again before printing.

  $row =~ s/new/old/gi;   # ... you need to use the variable here, instead of "$_"
  # The additional "i" behind the "g", makes the search for "new", "New", "NEW" case insensitive.
  # Credits to other answer and comments for finding the requirement I missed.

  # I accept the requirement to replace new->old, though it seems strange.
  # I itched to replace old->new.

  print $fhout $row; # print into the output file instead of to stdout
  # You had an additional "\n" at the end, which was in fact needed, but only
  # because of the "chomp" a few lines above.
  # Also, you had the variable in quotes, i.e. "$row\n". That uses some time for interpreting
  # the text inside the quotes. If you only want to print the content of a variable, then
  # only print the variable outside of quotes.
}

# There was the code "$_ =~ s/new/old/g;" here, it was moved into the loop.
# Compare to a different answer to see a solution which used a single global replace on
# a variable with all the input. Instead, I decided to go for line by line processing in
# a loop, because it seemed closer to your approach.

# There was the code "open( $fh, '>', 'output.txt');" here it was moved to before the loop.
# There was the code "print $filename ;" here. It was deleted, because it seems not to be
# required by the assignment. Printing the modified content is done line by line inside the
# loop. 

# Closing file handles instead of file name:
close $fhin;  
close $fhout;
```

*(StackOverflow recommends not to immediatly provide complete solutions for homework questions.

I interpret that as "... for homework questions which are not already close to solution".

I provided a solution because I considered your attempt very much close enough.

Close enough to show you the last details in comparision to something which works. Take that as a compliment.

StackOverflow also recommends to take students a little further along the way they can already see, in a helpful manner. Providing only the optimised, fine tuned final version, as the one start of this answer, is not constructive for them.

This is of course no excuse for any really bad code in my answer, so everybody feel free to point it out. When editing however, please stick to my goal, staying close to OPs attempt.)*

Comment: Don't predeclare variables. Use 3-arg open, never 2-arg open. Why do you concatenate `$filename` separately but interpolate `$!`? Your substitution is case sensitive.

Comment: @fugu Your edit fixed a few things, but you removed the filenames from the error messages (bad) and the substitution is still case sensitive.

Comment: As a very minor style point - I prefer `print {$out} $row;`. There's a couple of reasons, the major one being: `print $out, $row,"\n"` works, but `print {$out}, $row, "\n"` is a syntax error.

Comment: @fugu I admit to be unhappy with your edits. Please give a reason for each of your changes. Especially the parts where I left OPs code in a comment, augmented by what happened to it. That I felt more useful for a homework question. Renaming an identifier in a way which keeps it similar to the one used by OP, extended by a distinguishing use-case related part seemed very appropriate to me. Please reason why you changed that. I really interested in your reasons, especially since some of your edits are supported by one of my heros here. But in some cases you went to far without reason.

Comment: @melpomene I mainly tried to stay close to OPs homework, in order to get a better benefit for OP in this situation. But I am open to feedback. So why not predeclare variables? In combination with explaining comments (which are admittedly a bit thin here) it seems to make sense to me.

Comment: I simply missed the case-insensitivity requirement while reading and concentrated at OPs code while writing. That is worth an edit.

Comment: I concatenated the content of the variable $filename explicitly, becaue I (probably wrongly as I now see from a different angle) has the impression that is what OP intended. I did not care about the fact that and how, OP also used ´$!`, which is not necessarily the filename.

Comment: I will rework the answer, compromising between the good feedback in comments and edit here and my idea to stay close to what OP achieved; for homework-specific helpfulness. Later.

Comment: Error messages due to `open` failure should incorporate the name of the file on my the operation had been attempted and indicate the failed operation.

Comment: @Yunnosch feel free to roll back my edits any time you want

Comment: @fugu Thanks for agreeing. But I will actually keep several of your changes. Rolling back is a signal I do not want to send, it would only be appropriate if I didn't like anything you did.

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm not agreeing at all. I'm just saying that you are free accept or reject my edits as you please. Better yet, why don't you edit your answer so that it represents what you consider to be a better answer?

Comment: @melpomene, fugu, sobrique, sinan I did the intended editing. What is still improveable now I have missed. So please comment (again), preferrably including reasons, I am not against also learning something (more) here. Otherwise thanks for the constructive feedback. The other comments (especially the one on "print {$out} $row") seem to target the edit not by me, let me know if some of them apply to my most recent version.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to write this is to use "input/output direction". This feature is available in all popular operating systems. This means that we write our code to read from STDIN and write to STDOUT and rely on the operating system to connect these to specific files.

Using this technique, your code reduces to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  s/new/old/gi;
  print;
}
```

And (assuming that we store this in a file called `new2old`), we would call it like this:

```
$ ./new2old < WK5input.txt > output.txt
```

This way we avoid having to do all of that tedious mucking about with filehandles and end up with a program which is far more flexible. For example, we can pipe the output from another process into our program like this:

```
$ ls | ./new2old
```

Hard-coding filenames in a program is generally not the best approach.

Comment: Using input output direction seems like a conflict with the homework situation, in the context of learning perl and not bash. The assignment requires "program that reads the input.txt file" not "reads stdin". For the goal of efficient solution on the other hand, using a perl script in a file seems a waste, a commandline one-liner can do that. My respect however for noticing the case requirement. I missed that.

Comment: I'm always in favour of interpreting homework requirement loosely if the student ends learning something that will be more useful in the real world.

Comment: Do so, it is a good case. But don't make traps for the student. I.e. explain where you consciously leave the assignment. Maybe provide an efficient solution and one for the homework. You should answer OPs question to be on topic, then put additional information in for the sake of other people reading the Q/A later.

Comment: But I believe that my solution solves the question that was asked. My program reads from the correct input file and writes to the correct output file if run using the example in my answer.

Comment: This is part of the question: "Write a Perl program that reads the input.txt file...". We seem to be of different opinion whether your answer matches this. The extreme case would be doing the replacement in sed, then pipe through a print-only perl script.

Comment: And my code does read the correct input file and write the correct output file **when given the correct parameters**. As a bonus, it does many other things as well. I know that if I was a teacher and was given a solution like mine, I wouldn't penalise it in any way. It's fine that you disagree, of course, but I'm not going to spend any longer discussing it.

Answer (score 2):

First off, thank you for mentioning that this is homework. I would recommend telling your instructor that you got help completing the assignment. Here is some advice along with some enhancements:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# Don't hardcode variable names, read them from
# the command line. But, make sure you tell the
# user what went wrong if they are not specified.

if (@ARGV != 2) {
    die "Need input and output filenames\n";
}

# Assign the filenames

my ($infile, $outfile) = @ARGV;

# Error messages due to open failure must indicate
# the name of the file on which the operaton was
# attempted and the nature of the operation.
# By enclosing filenames in nonspace characters,
# you make it obvious if there are some unexpected
# characters in the name of the file.

open my $in, '<', $infile
    or die "Cannot open '$infile' for reading: $!";

open my $out, '>', $outfile
    or die "Cannot open '$outfile' for writing: $!";

while (my $line = <$in>) {
    # No need to chomp (remove the EOL) if you are just
    # going to print lines to another file
    $line =~ s/old/new/;

    # There is no comma between the output filehandle and
    # the string to be printed. If you put a comma, you will
    # get the stringification of $out and $line both printed
    # on STDOUT.
    print $out $line;
}

# While lexical filehandles are automatically closed
# when they go out of scope, it is good to explicitly
# close them, especially handles opened for writing.
#
# We did not check if each print succeeded. This is
# your last chance to find out if everything worked.

close $out
    or die "Failed to close output handle to '$outfile': $!";

close $in
    or die "Failed to close input handle to '$infile': $!";
```

Answer (score -2):

Just try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

my $filename = 'WK5input.txt';

open(my $tmp, "<", $filename) or die "Couldn't able to open a file...: $!\n";
my $storeline = "";
while(my $line = <$tmp>)
{
    $line=~s/new/old/g;
    $storeline .= $line;
}

open(my $out, ">", "Output.txt") or die "Couldn't able to open a file...: $!\n";
print $out $storeline;
close($out);
close($tmp);
```

There is a ***multiple way*** to do the task while handling the I/O. This is based on your question/understanding purpose only.

And also you couldn't you the temporarily variable [special variable] once you closed the while loop.

```
 $_ =~ s/new/old/g;
 open( $fh, '>', 'output.txt');
```

Comment: Can you explain the parts where you implemented most differently from OPs attempt? It is a homework question (with very visible attempt close to solution)  and therefor needs more explanation than solution.

Comment: _This is what I have so far but can't seem to get anywhere. Please help._ Already the OP's attempt very close to the solution obviously they knew what they will tried in the code. So then simply mentioned and I/O operating for OPEN/CLOSE. There is no need for each and every line to explain the code's. Also OP's needed to have the solution and where they want to replace the things doing in the replace (I have mentioned the problem).

Comment: Use lexical variables, not bareword filehandles. Use 3-arg open, never 2-arg open. Always include the name of the script and the file in the open error message. Don't predeclare variables. Don't clobber `$_` for no reason. Your substitution is case sensitive.

Comment: Storing all the lines to be printed makes the memory footprint of your program proportional to the size of the input. Programs that do ingest one line and spit it out after modifying will work for arbitrary input. Yours is going to bring the whole system to its knees when faced with large input files. Now, it is sometimes good to accumulate a small number of lines and print only occasionally, but usually the system's buffering does a good enough job that that is not needed.